# Separating async requests and saving using aiohttp

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am currently calling an external API many times and downloading the response's content from each call. I am using aiohttp and asyncio to speed up this process, but am having trouble figuring out how to separate the fetch functionality from the save functionality.

### Setup

```py
import asyncio
import os

from aiohttp import ClientSession
```

Currently, I am using the following function:

```py
async def fetch_and_save(link, path, client):
    async with await client.get(link) as response:
        contents = await response.read()

        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(path)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path))
        with open(path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(contents)
```

My main call looks like this:

```py
async def fetch_and_save_all(inputs):
    async with ClientSession() as client:
        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_and_save(link, path, client))
                 for link, path in inputs]
        for f in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
            await f


def main(inputs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(fetch_and_save_all(inputs))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputs = [
        (f"https://httpbin.org/range/{i}", f"./tmp/{i}.txt") for i in range(1, 10)]
    main(inputs)
```

Given this basic example, is it possible to separate the fetch and save functionality in `fetch_and_save`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "separate"? What's the desired end result or interface? Of course you can simply move the saving code to a separate function, but I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: @sytech I'm really having a difficult time mocking the fetching and think that the saving complicates the process.

Comment: I see. Wouldn't simply moving the respective code for fetching and saving to their own functions solve that? e.g. `fetch_and_save` would do something like `await save(await fetch(...))` Then the respective functions can be mocked independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create independent functions for `fetch` portion and `save` portion.

```py
async def fetch(link, client):
    async with await client.get(link) as response:
        contents = await response.read()
    return contents

def save(contents, path):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(path)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path))
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        bytes_written = f.write(contents)
    return bytes_written

async def fetch_and_save(link, path, client):
    contents = await fetch(link, client)
    save(contents, path)
```